# Error in mockito when method

Tags: junit4, mockito

I'm just trying to stub the method but getting null pointer exception. I'm kinda blank what's going on here.

my method :

```
OauthStatus validate(HttpServletRequest request, 
            boolean accessTokenRequired) throws OauthProviderException;
```

and Stub is :

```
Mockito.when(oauthProviderMock.validate((MockHttpServletRequest) Mockito.anyObject(), (boolean)Mockito.anyBoolean())).
                thenReturn(new OauthStatus());
```

i see there is no wrong in mocking but throws nullpointer exception.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: The stack trace of NPE will be useful.

Comment: Stack trace is Null..just Cause is Nullpointer exception.

Comment: Did you tried the debugger to see which object exactly is null?

Comment: Yes.tried it but it is the reponse obj which is null..

Comment: Can you post more of your code please?  In particular, how are you creating the mock at `oauthProviderMock`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Work around is Mocked the method through programmatically by using anonymous class instead of Mockito.

ex:

```
  oauthProvider = new OauthProvider(){

      validate( HttpServletRequest req, boolean flag) throws Exception{
           throw new RuntimeException();
       }

 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your casts to `(MockHttpServletRequest)` and `(boolean)` so it looks like this

```
Mockito.when(oauthProviderMock.validate(Mockito.any(HttpServletRequest.class), Mockito.anyBoolean())).
        thenReturn(new OauthStatus());
```

According to the [anyObject API](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html#anyObject%28%29) it will return `null` so you are probably seeing your `NPE` here.

According to the [anyBoolean API](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html#anyBoolean%28%29) it will return `false` so there should be no need to cast.

Comment: If I take off the cast to MockHttpServletRequest then it complains that , it is not applicable for argments Object,boolean.

Comment: Try using Mockito.any(HttpServletRequest.class) for that parameter

Comment: I think that Mockito.<HttpServletRequest>anyObject() should also work.